# How to get list of photos to a ListElement of a xaml page?

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-async

I m building a windows phone 8.1 application and using WinRT I need to capture a photo from my and need to display the captured photos as a list.
I written the following code but I am unable to run it and I'm getting errors. 
Can any1 please correct this ?

Code:

```
private async void BtnCapturePhoto_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)     
{         
    BtnCapturePhoto.IsEnabled = false;

    var photoStorageFile = await cameraCapture.CapturePhoto();         
    var bitmap = new BitmapImage();

    await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(await photoStorageFile.OpenReadAsync());

    PhotoListView.Items.Add(bitmap);
    BtnCapturePhoto.IsEnabled = true;       
}
```

Errors:

Following are the errors when I run the application:

Error1

```
The best overloaded method match for 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.SetSourceAsync(Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream)' has some invalid arguments
```

Error2

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream'
```

Error3

```
'object' does not contain a definition for 'OpenReadAsync' and no extension method 'OpenReadAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that photoStorageFile is a System.Object type in your code but it's a StorageFile in reality, so we first need to downcast it.

```
// Get the photoStorageFile as StorageFile not System.Object
StorageFile photoStorageFile = await cameraCapture.CapturePhoto() as StorageFile;

// Now we can properly set the source of the bitmapImage
using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await photoStorageFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
{
     // Set the image source to the selected bitmap
     BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

     await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
     bitmap.Source = bitmapImage;
}
```

this code should work

Comment: Thanks for your help but whenever the above code you mentioned I'm getting the following error:                  'object' does not contain a definition for 'OpenAsync' and no extension method 'OpenAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

Comment: what's the type of photoStorageFile ? is it a "StorageFile" class object ?

Comment: No,its not StorageFile Class object.

Comment: tell me the class and i will correct my answer accordingly!

Comment: Souchet I m using it as a variable.

Comment: do you understand what var means ? it's not just a "variable", it has a type as well, C# is a typed language it's not javascrit. so in Visual studio when you put your cursor on "photoStorageFile" you will see that it has a type

Comment: ohh! thanks man for letting me know it.I'm a newbie so I don't know. The class System.Object

Comment: System.Object is the base class in C#, i think it should be a StorageFile so you should cast it. Try StorageFile photoStorageFile = await cameraCapture.CapturePhoto();   or try StorageFile photoStorageFile = await cameraCapture.CapturePhoto() as StorageFile;

Comment: Wow cool!! It worked man... the 2nd option cleared all errors..Thanks..!

Comment: glad it worked, edited the question to write the right updated answer